# Движок для хостинга

Tags: php, linux, apache2

Логика ресурса - у каждого пользователя папка site.com/папка, в которой он волен делать все что хочет(только в ней без доступа к остальному). Что то вроде мини хостинга. Виртуальный сервер арендовал, но сам не силен в администрировании линукс. Вопрос. Есть ли готовые решения, для органиции такого мини хостинга.

Comment: для доступа,это ни как не организовать,тебе нужно арендовать сервер,и при помощи любого языка программирывания сделать доступ к этой папке,только с этим могут возникнуть проблемы,по скольку везде есть лазейки...если не знаешь надо выучить советую для работы с серверами сначала начать с php потом js и.т.д,по скольку тебе могут предложить вариант с такой дырой что ты понесешь такие убытки (если не материальные то времени ты потратишь будь сдоров...) советую начать учить,дабы потом в этом разбиратся..

Comment: php я знаю нормально, нет времени разбираться с командной строкой и прочими фишками линукс

Comment: Тогда лучше вообще не заниматься этим

Comment: а ISPmanager разве не подойдет?

Comment: Когда клиенты придут к тебе с `мы деньги платим, почему всё лежит?` подумаешь о том, что не мешало бы разбираться в том, чем занимаешься.

Comment: Со словами это ещё ничего. А могут и с битами. Рабираться за порушеный бизнес.  А могут и "органы" прийти. Когда на взломанных сайтах будет что-то эдакое.. типа экстремизма или детского порно. [Поучительные истории](http://searchengines.guru/showpost.php?p=14347422&postcount=17)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. 
сPanel или ISPmanager думаю будут оптимальными вариантами в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли готовые решения, для органиции такого мини хостинга.

Бесплатная панель [VestaCP](http://vestacp.com/) с русскоязычной поддержкой на оффоруме.